# How to add values to key and save autocompletion with JLine?

Tags: java, autocomplete, jline

I'm trying to implement a simple shell application with autocompletion. I use `JLine` library for it. Don't know maybe it's a common issue, but when I try to add some value to the parameter my autocompletion doesn't work.

Here is my code snippet

```
public class ConsoleDemo {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        try {
            ConsoleReader console = new ConsoleReader();
            console.setPrompt("> ");

            StringsCompleter exit = new StringsCompleter("exit");

            StringsCompleter login = new StringsCompleter("connect");
            StringsCompleter loginParams = new StringsCompleter("--url", "--username", "--password");

            StringsCompleter export = new StringsCompleter("export");
            StringsCompleter exportParam = new StringsCompleter("to");

            ArgumentCompleter loginCompleter = new ArgumentCompleter(login, loginParams);
            ArgumentCompleter exportCompleter = new ArgumentCompleter(export, exportParam);

            console.addCompleter(loginCompleter);
            console.addCompleter(exportCompleter);
            console.addCompleter(exit);

            String line;
            while ((line = console.readLine()) != null) {
                if ("exit".equals(line.trim())) {
                    exit(1);
                }
                console.println(line.trim() + valueOf(-1));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I write

`login --url http://localhost:8080/server`

I'm not able to use tab key for autocomplete `password`.

`login --url http://localhost:8080/server --us` (press tab for completion) <- doesn't work too

That should I do to get next hint for `--username` and `--password`?

Answer (score 0):

Your login completer is using the "connect" string as an identifier, not login....